# Not sure what is the result of this right outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

Right outer join is similar to a `Union` of a venn diagram right?
I mean for `A right outer Join B` we should get all the rows of `B` and any matching rows in `A`.
For some reason I am confused with the following:
Assume table `Orders`:

```
mysql> select * from orders;  
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+  
| orderedon  | name       | partnum | quantity | remarks |  
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+  
| 1996-05-19 | TRUE-WHEEL |      76 |        3 | PAID    |  
| 1996-09-02 | TRUE-WHEEL |      10 |        1 | PAID    |   
| 1996-06-30 | TRUE-WHEEL |      42 |        8 | PAID    |   
| 1996-06-30 | BIKE SPEC  |      54 |       10 | PAID    |  
| 1996-05-30 | BIKE SPEC  |      23 |        8 | PAID    |   
| 1996-01-17 | BIKE SPEC  |      76 |       11 | PAID    |  
| 1996-01-17 | LE SHOPPE  |      76 |        5 | PAID    |  
| 1996-06-01 | LE SHOPPE  |      10 |        3 | PAID    |  
| 1996-06-01 | AAA BIKE   |      10 |        1 | PAID    |   
| 1996-07-01 | AAA BIKE   |      76 |        4 | PAID    |  
| 1996-07-01 | AAA BIKE   |      46 |       14 | PAID    |   
| 1996-07-11 | JACKS BIKE |      76 |       14 | PAID    |  
| 1996-05-15 | TRUE-WHEEL |      23 |        6 | PAID    |  
| 1996-05-30 | BIKE SPEC  |      20 |        2 | PAID    |   
+------------+------------+---------+----------+---------+   
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and table `Part`:

```
mysql> select * from part;  
+---------+---------------+---------+  
| partnum | description   | price   |  
+---------+---------------+---------+  
|      54 | PEDALS        |   54.25 |  
|      42 | SEATS         |   24.50 |  
|      46 | TIRES         |   15.25 |  
|      23 | MOUNTAIN BIKE |  350.45 |  
|      76 | ROAD BIKE     |  530.00 |  
|      10 | TANDEM        | 1200.00 |  
+---------+---------------+---------+  
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was expecting that the following query:
`select p.partnum p_partnum,p.description p_desc,p.price p_price,o.name o_name,o.partnum o_partnum from part p right outer join orders o on o.partnum=54;`
Would give me all the rows of `Orders` and just the rows of `part` that have `partnum=54`.
But I get this:

```
mysql> select p.partnum p_partnum,p.description p_desc,p.price p_price,o.name   o_name,o.partnum o_partnum from part p right outer join orders o on o.partnum=54;   
+-----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+  
| p_partnum | p_desc        | p_price | o_name     | o_partnum |  
+-----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+  
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | TRUE-WHEEL |        76 |  
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | TRUE-WHEEL |        10 |   
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | TRUE-WHEEL |        42 |   
|        54 | PEDALS        |   54.25 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |   
|        42 | SEATS         |   24.50 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |   
|        46 | TIRES         |   15.25 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |   
|        23 | MOUNTAIN BIKE |  350.45 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |    
|        76 | ROAD BIKE     |  530.00 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |   
|        10 | TANDEM        | 1200.00 | BIKE SPEC  |        54 |   
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | BIKE SPEC  |        23 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | BIKE SPEC  |        76 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | LE SHOPPE  |        76 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | LE SHOPPE  |        10 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | AAA BIKE   |        10 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | AAA BIKE   |        76 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | AAA BIKE   |        46 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | JACKS BIKE |        76 |   
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | TRUE-WHEEL |        23 |    
|      NULL | NULL          |    NULL | BIKE SPEC  |        20 |    
+-----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+   
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why am I getting the extra rows? Why does it combine the row of `Order` with `partnum=54` to all rows of `part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM part p 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders o 
  ON o.partnum=54
```

...only has a condition on order, what you need to add is a condition that the part also corresponds to the order, or the database will consider any part a match;

```
FROM part p 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders o 
  ON o.partnum=54
 AND o.partnum = p.partnum
```

Of course, if you only want to show the rows where partnum=54, you're better off moving the `o.partnum=54` to a `WHERE` condition instead. `JOIN` conditions are usually for connecting tables, `WHERE` usually for filtering.

Comment: So it does something like a cartesian products when it has a row of orders with partnum 54?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have any join condition that specifies the relation between o and p, you get a cartesian join.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Your query is

```
select p.partnum p_partnum,p.description p_desc,p.price p_price,o.name   o_name,o.partnum o_partnum 
from part p right outer join orders o on o.partnum=54;
```

You are going for right join so even if there is no match in the joining table on the right side it will display records and it is happening in this case of your query

same is for left join there all the records of the table on the left side will be displayed even if they dont match

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp

For detailed explanation

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `RIGHT JOIN` to `orders` with join condition `partnum=54` you will get all rows from `orders` joined with `parts` when `partnum=54`. You have one row with `partnum=54` and that row joined with all rows (cross join) from `parts`.

Comment: So it performs cartesian product for this row?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `o.partnum = 54` on `ON condition`, that's why you're getting extra rows
in your result.

You need to put the condition `o.partnum = 54` on where clause.

How about this

```
select p.partnum p_partnum,p.description p_desc,p.price p_price,o.name o_name,o.partnum  o_partnum 
from part p right outer join orders o 
on o.partnum = p.partnum
where o.partnum=54;
```

Edit : You may refer to this [beautiful article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231132/Difference-between-On-clause-and-Where-clause-when) how the result set gets disturb when you
put condition on ON clause and Where.